# Solving four simultaneous equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am thinking how to solve the four simultaneous equations for $x,y,z,u$
where $\beta, c, a, b$ are arbitrary real numbers.

$$\frac{a-x}{b} - z - u = 0,\\ x - min(\beta u, c y)  =0,\\ x -y = 0,\\ x-1 = 0$$

From the last two equations we have $x=1, y=1$ but we have to find values of $z, u$ as well.

In the second equation, we will have $1 - min(\beta u, c) = 0$ but then after that how we proceed?

We consider two cases, suppose $min(\beta u, c) = \beta u$, then $u = \frac{1}{\beta}$. Next we consider the other case, $min(\beta u, c) = c$, then we get $c = 1$ but $c $ is an arbitrary real number..

If $u = \frac{1}{\beta}$, then from the first equation we have $z = \frac{a-1}{b} - \frac{1}{\beta}$. So $(x,y,z,u) = (1,1,\frac{a-1}{b} - \frac{1}{\beta}, \frac{1}{\beta})$.

For the second case, we had $c = 1$ and thus from the first equation, we have $z+u = \frac{a-1}{b}$..this can have infinite solutions

So I am puzzled which one should I consider

Comment: You have to distinguish different cases depending on the values of $\beta$ and $c$ in order to find $u$.

Comment: If this really does have a solution, then $\beta u$ must be $1$ or else I don't think its possible to find a solution

Comment: If $c<1$, there is no solution for $u$ and hence $z$.  If $c\ge 1$ then you have already solved the system as the first case.

Comment: More generally, if $c < 1$, then the last three equations have no solution regardless of $z$ and the first equation. The last two equations require $x = 1, y = 1$, which makes the second equation $1 = \min\{\beta u, c\}$. But if $c < 1$ then $\min\{\beta u,c\} \le c < 1$ and so cannot be $1$, no matter the value of $\beta u$.